# ArcGIS Service Backend Deletion: does anyone have instructions to remove a service from the server itself (filesystem/registry/etc)?

Tags: arcgis-server, feature-service, arcgis-enterprise

I have a rogue service on a a single-server ArcGIS Enterprise instance which, after spending quite a bit of time on the horn with ESRI, I've been unable to delete (or stop, for that matter).  We've looked at locks, missing files, and permissions, and of course tried everything under the sun from the Server Manager, Server Administrator, and ArcGIS Catalog interfaces.

Surely, there must be a workflow to clear out an angry service from the machine itself.

Comment: Workflow, maybe, but not a supported one, and certainly not better than what Support could suggest/lead you through.  Without critical details, it would be irresponsible to recommend anything. And if the instance is that unstable, you're probably best off just standing up a new server.

Comment: Standing up a whole new server because of a service that wont go away? Yikes, thats incredibly heavy handed.

Comment: Yeah this instance has actually been pretty good for a bit, the problem is contained to one service for now.

Comment: I had something similar but not exactly the same once. The fix for me was to republish the service with the overwrite option. I could then stop and delete it.

Comment: We tried that here, but the service was stuck.  KHimba's process did the trick though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some quick troubleshooting steps in order:

Re-start all the Enterprise components (Portal, Server, Datastore). If the ArcSOC.exe process is still there after stopping these, simply kill it in task manager.

If the process/service comes back after restarting Enterprise, then its referenced in the config-store somewhere. Look at `$:\arcgisserver\directories\arcgissystem\arcgisinput` for the folder it resides in. Try deleting the **service named folder** inside the input directory (you may need to stop Enterprise again).  Note - if you have a distributed Enterprise (multiple machines), your config store might be on a shared drive, or drive *not* local to the Server box itself.

Comment: I'll let you know how it goes.  You think I'll be able to delete the service by restarting the server after removing the arcgisserver directories?   I'll let you know if that works overnight when I can turn the machine off.

Comment: Only remove the __single__ directory inside the arcgisinput directory that corresponds to your service. Removing all directories in there and you're starting with a broken Server.

Comment: Oh, I was only going to remove the service's specific directory though I intended on removing the arcgisserver\outputs service directory as well.  I didn't get clearance to try this though... the admin is concerned about messing around with those files (gee I wonder why).

Comment: Sure you can nuke everything, but treading lightly is generally pretty safe. Especially if you just do a copy and put the contents elsewhere instead of fully deleting. Odds are, after an Enterprise re-start, all should be good without having to go down this path. Hopefully that's all it took.

Comment: After waiting for ESRI to look into this for a week, they got back to me with what are basically your instructions, so the admin was on board and I went for it.  It worked.  I may or may not have tried this in the first place btw, but didn't want to interrupt our data so didn't restart the service and ended up putting everything back where I found it because nothing changed.  Turns out that the service restart is essential.  FWIW, I stopped the service, deleted the folders, then restarted.